# Nebular Dialog Alignment

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, nebular

As the Title says i'm currently struggeling with the [Nebular Dialog](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/dialog) in Angular.
It is centered by default and i want it to be aligned straight to the right of my screen.

What i tried so far after googling quite a while is to call the dialog in my `component.ts` like so:

```js
this.dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(this.noteDialog, { dialogClass: 'stick-right' });
```

and then adding some scss to my `themes.scss`

```css
.stick-right {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
```

what this does is some html output as following when inspecting the elements in the Browser (simplified)

```html
<div class="cdk-global-overlay-wrapper" style="justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <div class="cdk-overlay-pane stick-right" style="position: static;">
        <app-notes></app-notes>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the `dialogClass: 'stick-right'` is applied to the second `<div>`.
So the problem here seems to be that i need the `scss` applied to the first `<div>` and not the second.

Anybody got a clue if thats possible from `NbDialog` itself or having a proper solution that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i finally found out myself...
I'm really not a friend of jquery but in this case it seems to be the only chance to get this done (until a parent selector will be added to css)...

With this the `stick-right` class will be added to the div element with class `cdk-global-overlay-wrapper`

```js
$('.cdk-overlay-pane').closest('.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper').addClass('stick-right');
```